# Create a record set based on an immutable object

Tags: immutable.js

I am receiving JSON data from an endpoint using Ajax.

```
const jsData = '[ {"x": 1, "y": 1}, {"x": 2, "y": 2}, … ]';
```

I am converting the data to an immutable object:

```
const imData = Immutable.fromJSON( jsData )
```

I want to create a record set base on this immutable object

```
const Rec = Immutable.Record( imData)
const rec = new Rec();
```

This error is thrown `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined`.

*NOTE: Why am I not directly passing the `jsData` to be the default values of the record set ?*
I don't want this to be possible: `rec[0].x = 1`.

What would be the correct way to convert the received data to a record set that is completely immutable ?

Answer (score 1):

1. Your JSON data sample is invalid JSON.
2. You are not posting code sample which produces the error. Message says 
   `Cannot read property 'get' of undefined.` while in your samples you don't call `get` on anything.

Use objects to create Record. https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Record

> A record is similar to a JS object, but enforces a specific set of
>   allowed string keys, and has default values.

```
const jsData = '[{"x":1,"y":1},{"x":2,"y":2}]';
const imData = JSON.parse(jsData)
console.log(imData)
const Rec = Immutable.Record( imData[0])
const rec = new Rec();

console.log(rec.get('x'));
```

https://jsfiddle.net/sh637wsm/